# Why would the Net::LDAP gem prevent tests from running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ldap

I have installed the ruby-net-ldap gem version 0.0.4 on my OS X (Snow Leopard) system. When I include the line...

```
config.gem('ruby-net-ldap')
```

in environment.rb, my tests won't run and I get this error...

```
Missing these required gems:
  ruby-net-ldap  

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.6.0 at /usr/local/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.3.5 at /Users/ethan/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

But the gem is definitely installed...

```
$ gem list -l | grep ldap
ruby-net-ldap (0.0.4)
```

My other gems are loading fine and presenting no problems...

```
  config.gem('mislav-will_paginate', :lib => 'will_paginate')
  config.gem('haml')
  config.gem('prawn')
  config.gem('thoughtbot-shoulda', :lib => 'shoulda/rails')
  config.gem('faker')
  config.gem('binarylogic-searchlogic', :lib => 'searchlogic')
  config.gem('fastercsv')
```

With the gem installed I am able to do LDAP queries in the Rails console, so it seems to be working sort of, just causing all the tests to error out.

Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `rake` running in the same Ruby environment as `gem`? Did you specify the correct `lib` directory?

```
config.gem 'ruby-net-ldap', :version => '0.0.4', :lib => 'net/ldap'
```